# Vb.Net Wait for Async Response

Tags: vb.net, loops, asynchronous

I am working on a windows form application which controls a number of stepper motors which in turn drive a camera. The stepper motors are controlled through an Arduino acting as a serial port.

In the app, the Arduino receives absolute position commands (e.g. x;23,y;90,z;120) and it then moves the various motors to those respective commands, whilst the motors are moving the arduino outputs the current position, then at the end I will have it output an x;OK,y;OK,z;OK response.

As the motor positions are received from the arduino, these are updated within the application on a status view, however within my code i actually need to loop like the below (pseudocode);

```
For i = LowerLimit to UpperLimit step IntervalStep
     com1.WriteLine("x;" & x ",y;" & y & ",z;" & i)
     'wait for OK response from Serial Port
     'Capture Image
next
```

How would I go about pausing the loop (thread) until I receive the OK response from the serial port?

Many Thanks!

Comment: could you include all the code related to declaring and making the connection to com1 please? Cheers.